# Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy netplan goes missing

Tags: ubuntu, iproute2, netplan

I would like to know if anybody experienced this.   I am running the server cli version of Ubuntu 22.04.
After running apt, I see a message saying to run apt autoremove.  (I did this)
I also got a message about a kernel update and to reboot (I rebooted)
Network never came up.

It did not take me long to realize that the **iproute2** package and the **netplan.io** package were both gone.   (both the ip and netplan commands were missing)

All interfaces (except lo were gone)

Without IP and Netplan, I had no network connection, so I went to https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy
to download packages in hopes of getting back up and running.
To get **iproute2_5.15.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb** I needed to also install:

- libbpf0_0.5.0-1_amd64.deb
- libcap2-bin_2.44-1build3_amd64.deb
- libmnl0_1.0.4-3build2_amd64.deb
- libxtables12_1.8.7-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb

Then to install **netplan.io_0.104-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb** I needed its depencencies:

- libc6_2.35-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
- libglib2.0-0_2.72.1-1_amd64.deb
- libnetplan0_0.104-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
- python3_3.10.4-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
- python3-netifaces_0.11.0-1build2_amd64.deb
- python3-yaml_5.4.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb

This actually fixed the networking problem and then I was able to run "apt --fix-broken install" to clean up whatever else happened.

Has anybody heard about this?  I have been running Ubuntu servers for long time and have not seen this before.

Comment: Could you share your apt history, this seems exceptionally weird (haven't checked bugs.ubuntu.com yet though).

Comment: Production machines would usually be installed/upgraded after the first *point release*. Call `lsb_release -a` to confirm that you are running `22.04.1` - if it instead shows as plain `22.04` there is a possibility that your installation was done using upgrade scripts or installation media before those methods were finalized for that release. In that case you might have had an installation that never matched release configuration in the first place.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify that this is not the result of a third-party dependency mess, e.g. by caling `grep -rh ^[^#] /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` to confirm you are exclusively using the Canonical-administered set of package sources for the codename `jammy` release.

Comment: Another way to mess up is to uninstall `cloud-init`. Which would be a (very) good idea, if it didn't also remove `netplan`, `dhcp-client`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is at least one installed software package called *metapackage* that ships little or no features on its own, but defines dependencies on everything you probably do not want automatically removed.

One way to get to the point you arrived at, is to remove the package `ubuntu-minimal`. Doing so is *rarely advisable* - but possible, should you truly have a valid reason to deviate from the system Canonical has designated as the *minimal* distribution. Install `ubuntu-minimal` (possibly also `ubuntu-server`) and have a closer look for other dependencies that are now (re)installed as a result.

The other way I know of is failure during upgrades, but in that case the scripts used to manage those upgrades should - unless interrupted by **power failure or running out of disk space** - always clearly log & output their progress - and suggest possible mitigation if things go awry.